# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln\ln n}{\ln n}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was looking at an old Upenn calc exam and saw this question:
Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{\ln\ln n}{\ln n}$ converge or diverge? Using Wolframalpha I was able to see that it diverges using the comparison test, but I'm not sure what series to compare it to. Perhaps the harmonic series since $\ln\ln n \gt1$ and $\ln n \lt n$. Is that correct?

Comment: Sounds right to me.

Comment: You don't even need comparison test. You can bound the partial sums from below and the lower bound diverges to $+\infty$. 
$$\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}
\ge \frac{\log\log 2}{\log 2} + \sum_{n=3}^N \frac{\log\log 3}{\log N}
= \frac{\log\log 2}{\log 2} + \frac{\log \log 3}{\log N}(N-2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n > e^e$

$$\frac{\ln \ln n}{\ln n} > \frac{1}{\ln n} > \frac{1}{n}$$

since $\ln \ln n$ is strictly increasing and $\ln n < n$. The sum of a converging series (the sum of the terms before $e^e$) and a diverging series is diverging, so this series diverges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this different from what I tried to suggest in the question?

Comment: @IsaacBorski No, but $\ln \ln n > 1$ is not always true. The trick is to split the summation up.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 1. $ f(x) = \dfrac{\ln x }{x} $ has $ f’(x) < 0 , x \ge 3$.

2. $ 1 < \ln n < n , n \ge 3 $.

   3. $a_n \ge \dfrac{\ln n}{n}$.

Can you continue ?

Comment: I'm not sure in what direction you are trying to go

Comment: @IsaacBorski DeepSea proved that last inequality by combining hints $1$ and $2$. From there you can use the integral test or the known divergence of the otherside.